# rosserial_client make_libraries: unable to build message

Tags: ros-noetic, rosserial-arduino, generate-messages

I am trying to create a custom message for ROS noetic and implement it in a rosserial_arduino node. To do that, I first created my workspace:

```
mkdir neopixel_ws
```

then, I cloned the rosserial_arduino into `src` directory, and I created (in `src` folder) other folder named `neopixel` which contains the `msg` folder with my custom message. My custom message contains the following lines:

```
uint8 red
uint8 green
uint8 blue

uint8 pixel_number

bool enable
```

then, I modified the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` as follows:

https://gist.github.com/LeonardoJulianOcampo/e209896e6e9df80b475d7f535b31effa

after that, I go to `neopixel_ws` root and execute:

```
catkin_make
```

when finished, I ran `catkin_make` and `source devel/setup.bash`.

Finally, I try generate the header files for rosserial_arduino of my custom message. To do so, I ran:

```
rosrun rosserial_client make_libraries /home/leo/Arduino/libraries/ neopixel_msgs
```

The output of this command indicates the following:

```
...

Exporting nav_msgs

  Messages:
    MapMetaData,OccupancyGrid,GridCells,GetMapActionResult,GetMapActionGoal,GetMapFeedback,GetMapActionFeedback,Path,GetMapAction,GetMapGoal,Odometry,GetMapResult,

  Services:
    LoadMap,GetMap,SetMap,GetPlan,

Exporting neopixel

  Messages:
    Unable to build message: neopixel/neopixel_msg
neopixel_msg,Exporting nodelet

  Services:
    NodeletLoad,NodeletList,NodeletUnload,

Exporting pcl_msgs

  Messages:
    Vertices,PolygonMesh,ModelCoefficients,PointIndices,

...
```

In the Arduino/libraries folder, the ros_lib folder is created with the default headers, but not with my custom message.

How can I resolve this? Is there any part of the process that I might be doing incorrectly? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before you do the `make_libraries` command, you need to source the setup.bash that was created inside your catkin workspace:

   ```
   cd neopixel_ws
   source devel/setup.bash
   ```
2. Also, your CMakeLists.txt file is missing stuff: it's missing `message_generation` in find_packages, and missing `message_runtime` in  catkin_package, and the generate_messages section is commented out.

Comment: Yes, I have done it, it gives the same result

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I made the modifications you mentioned, and initially, with the command 'rosrun rosserial_client make_libraries path_to_libraries neopixel_msgs', I was getting the same output. Then I tried using the command 'rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py path_to_libraries', which gives me the same message. However, this time, unlike the previous command, the process correctly generates the header for the desired message. It's strange, but at least it's working now. Thanks.